# MySQL query - Invalid Use of Group Function - Using SUM

Tags: mysql

I am having "Invalid use of group function" error while executing following query.

```
Select id, faultdistribution, faulttype, faultseverity, 
SUM(IF (faultdistribution='crs', SUM(IF(faultdistribution='crs',1,0))*8, 0)+
IF (faultdistribution='configuration', SUM(IF(faultdistribution='configuration',1,0))* 6, 0)+
IF (faulttype='business' AND faultseverity='fatal', SUM(IF(faulttype='business' AND faultseverity='fatal',1,0))* 4, 0)+
IF (faulttype='business' AND faultseverity='major', SUM(IF(faulttype='business' AND faultseverity='major',1,0))* 2, 0)+
IF (faulttype='business' AND faultseverity='moderate', SUM(IF(faulttype='business' AND faultseverity='moderate',1,0))* 5, 0)+
IF (faulttype='business' AND faultseverity='minor', SUM(IF(faulttype='business' AND faultseverity='minor',1,0))* 3, 0)+
IF (faulttype='look & feel' AND faultseverity='fatal', SUM(IF(faulttype='look & feel' AND faultseverity='fatal',1,0))* 2, 0)+
IF (faulttype='look & feel' AND faultseverity='major', SUM(IF(faulttype='look & feel' AND faultseverity='major',1,0))* 1, 0))
FROM tbl_fault WHERE product='DAS' AND faultdistribution='missed'
```

Where i am doing it wrong? Kindly help!

Comment: Is id the unique key for that table? If so how do you want to group things up over rows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SUM(), COUNT(), AVG(), MIN(), MAX(), etc. are aggregate functions that requires you to specify a GROUP BY, unless you're using them on every column in your SELECT-list.

In your case, the query should work by adding the following at the bottom:

```
GROUP BY id, faultdistribution, faulttype, faultseverity
```

...but judging from the many nested IF's you have, I'm not entirely sure that this would give you the output you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

try this shortened query

```
 Select id, faultdistribution, faulttype, faultseverity, 
 IF (faultdistribution='crs', 1,0)*8 +
 IF (faultdistribution='configuration', 1,0)* 6 +
 IF (faulttype='business' AND faultseverity='fatal', 1,0)* 4 +
 IF (faulttype='business' AND faultseverity='major', 1,0)* 2 +
 IF (faulttype='business' AND faultseverity='moderate', 1,0)* 5 +
 IF (faulttype='business' AND faultseverity='minor', 1,0)* 3 +
 IF (faulttype='look & feel' AND faultseverity='fatal', 1,0)* 2 +
 IF (faulttype='look & feel' AND faultseverity='major', 1,0)* 1 as mysum
 FROM tbl_fault WHERE product='DAS' AND faultdistribution='missed'
 group by id , faultdistribution ,faulttype ,faultseverity
```

Comment: @OmerZia try this shortened query

Comment: that's a great help! :)

Comment: Here is the schema : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d2aac/19 
While executing this query in PHP i am having **46** as a result. The result should be 6

Comment: i see just entries in your demo , can you put the whole data , so i can look at it ?

Comment: i mean where is 46 results , fill them by your data, in your example there is only 2 entries, so i dont know if it will get 6 results.